# Waypoints with orientation + Smooth trajectory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a ground robot ( 4 wheels like a car) a I have my missions defined by a set of waypoints ( x, y, yaw (position and orientation)). I want that my robot moves through these waypoints with the specified orientation in each waypoints. The path should be smooth (using splines or Bezier curve) but intersect the waypoints.

Does anyone known any package for this purpose?

Regards,
Filipe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47219/waypoints-with-orientation-+-smooth-trajectory/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [pose_follower](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pose_follower) is a local planner that implements the [BaseLocalPlanner](http://ros.org/wiki/nav_core#BaseLocalPlanner) interface and tries to follow a given plan (AFAIK with orientation per waypoint) as closely as possible. It will only follow a given plan and not modify it, so if you have sparse waypoints the tracking might not look smooth (then you would have to first generate a smoothed trajectory in a preceding step). It might has to be modified to work well with a Ackermann-steered vehicle, however.

If you really want to plan for a Ackermann-Steering vehicle I can recommend looking into the [SBPL lattice planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl_lattice_planner). It uses lattice (motion primitive) based plans and thus also can plan for Ackermann steering vehicles. The existing ROS package is not able to consider multiple waypoints though, so you'd have to write code yourself that creates a plan between two of your waypoints and then concatenates those small plans into a single large one. Note that this solution provides obstacle avoidance capabilities.

If you do not want to consider obstacles, you could probably implement spline/bezier curver interpolation yourself, I'm not sure there is a package available that does this.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-10-31**:
thanks Stefan :) your suggestions are good and I will try use them. But if anyone's knows other package that implements spliner/bezier curve, that suggestions are welcome. (because i wan't to try a navigation with this curves and provably I will try to implement them)

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2014-01-21**:
Has any extra information been found by either of you (or anyone else on this matter).  I myself have already modified SBPL Lattice Planner and made have an overhead waypoint system, but need the local planner that can generate the desired paths.  Currently making my own, but another may be better.